# Can't get a reference of directive inside Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

I got a little stuck trying to check the presence of certain directive inside my component.

I have this  component implemented making use of a custom template:

```html
<card-list [items]="data">
    <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
      <div>

        <!-- Card image -->
        <img card-image src="./assets/images/default.png" alt="{{ item.target_url }}">

        <!-- Card content middle -->
        <div class="mt-4 md:mt-0 md:ml-6 flex-grow">
          ...

        </div>

        <!-- Card content right -->
        <div class="mt-4 md:mt-0 md:ml-6">
          ...

        </div>

      </div>
    </ng-template>
</card-list>
```

In this component I use the optional directive `card-image`. Which I want to "capture" inside the card component.

### CardListComponent (card-list.html):

```html
<card *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
    <ng-content select="[card-image]"></ng-content>

    <!-- Default card template -->
    <ng-container *ngIf="!itemTemplateRef">
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Custom template -->
    <ng-container
      *ngIf="itemTemplateRef"
      [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplateRef"
      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: item, index: i }">
    </ng-container>
</card>
```

I want to get a reference of the image passed within the `card-image` directive to show or hide a checkbox component.

### CardImage Directive:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[card-image]',
  host: {'class': 'card-image'}
})
export class CardImage {}
```

### CardComponent:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'card',
  exportAs: 'card',
  templateUrl: 'card.html',
  styleUrls: ['card.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  host: {
    'class': 'card focus-indicator',
  }
})
export class Card implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  @ViewChild(CardImage, {static: true}) cardImg: CardImage;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('this.cardImg', this.cardImg);
  }

}
```

`console.log('this.cardImg')` always shows `undefined`. I've tried using `@ContentChild` or inspecting changes with `@ContentChildren`/`@ViewChildren`. With no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: what happens when you change the directive's selector from selector: '[card-image]' to selector: '[cardImg]'?

Comment: I see you using `itemTemplateRef` in your template, but where do you pass it into your component?